# Version control/backup for postgres database

Tags: database, postgresql, version-control, database-backups

I recently executed an incorrect UPDATE query (yes, ouch) and turns out my company doesn't have any recent backup for me to restore the data. Are there any version control tools or automated backup techniques that I can use so this doesn't happen again

Answer (score 0):

[Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/), while it mainly oriented on managed schema-changes, it can be (TBT!) (with the same concept of roll-backed changesets) used for data-changes

Answer (score 0):

Version control tools and automated backup techniques are different things

Regarding the automated backup tools here are some examples :

- [pgbarman](https://pgbarman.org/) : We use it in our organization
- [pgbackrest](https://pgbackrest.org/)